# Preferred way to start a download in a browser

Tags: html

We are currently using a meta refresh to initiate a download on a page, I read on Wikipedia that using this is not UX (user experience) friendly.  So what is the way to have a download start after a few seconds when landing on a download page.

Comment: In my opinion, landing pages and user friendly don't go together. Remove the landing page altogether or at least remove the automatic download and have the user click a link.

Comment: @casablanca HA, that is what we had, but the customer wants it to start automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User interface-friendly way would:

1. Not spring an unannounced surprise to the user. So postpone the download by X seconds and clearly announce that.

   This is done by setting up JavaScript logic to display a changing countdown to download. See below for details on implementation.
2. Allow user to control this by allowing immediate download

   This is done by having the download timer announcement provide a widget (button or a link) to download immediately.
3. Keep the current page, by opening the download in a new window/tab.

   The "kick off the download" logic should preferably be - instead of the obvious setting of `window.location.href` - something which opens a new window for the download. This way you allow the user to keep the main download landing page intact.
4. If possible, present a nice download widget

   Instead of just pushing the URL of the download target, consider using custom download wisget like jQuery's [jDownload plugin](http://jdownloadplugin.com/)

---

To implement the changing countdown, do something like this:

- Set up a variable for how long till download starts:

  `var DownloadIn = 10;`
- Set up a timer in JavaScript using setTimeout()`:

  `setTimeout("shouldWeDownload()", DownloadIn * 1000);`
- Subroutine `shouldWeDownload()` called from a timer will:

  - check if time period (stored in `DownloadIn` variable) is greater than zero.
  - If the time is NOT up (greater than zero), it will:

    a. Check if a special "AlreadyDownloading" variable is set to true - this variable will be explained later. If true, simply exit.

    b. print to a special DIV on the page - something very obvious and visible to the user - a message "XXX seconds left till the start of download. Click on [*this link*](http://aaa) to start the download".

    c. Decrement `DownloadIn` variable

    d. Set the timer again using the same `setTimeout`
  - If the time's up, kick off the download.
- In addition, the "*this link*" link in the message would also immediately kick off the download. To make things clean, the "immediate dowload" onClick JS handler should set a special "AlreadyDownloading" variable which is checked in the logic above should be set to true, so we don't start a second download due to minor race conditions.

Comment: This doesn't help at all. If people are paying attention, they would just click the link instead of waiting. If they're not, then it would still be a surprise popup after X seconds.

Comment: @casablanca - if you design your GUI so that the DIV with the message is obvious, it will help.

Comment: Like I said, if the message is in fact obvious, they would simply click the link instead of waiting 10 seconds.

Comment: @casablanca - it's a question of control. If a notional user has a download pop-up spring on me un-expectedly, he can freak out.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of any research on what users expect, but I’d suggest mentioning that it’s a download in your initial download link, e.g.

```
<a href="kiss_from_a_rose__dubstep_remix.mp3">Download my awesome track</a>
```

(Maybe style that link like a big button, maybe even with an arrow pointing downwards in it: e.g. [something like this](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://s3.envato.com/files/119762.jpg&imgrefurl=http://graphicriver.net/item/premium-download-button-template/42609&usg=__sSzimWyXTAuoyWFDEI6txVhMqss=&h=581&w=590&sz=335&hl=en&start=16&sig2=JSPTO3h4fzQp_oNfc9vo1Q&zoom=1&tbnid=UJkrQBTQEVV_XM%3a&tbnh=133&tbnw=135&ei=PCbkTNMdgbuEB6SIsYMO&prev=/images%3Fq%3Ddownload%2Bbutton%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DX%26biw%3D1280%26bih%3D680%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1).)

And then set your server to return that file with [the `Content-disposition` header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) set to 'attachment' and the name of the file, so that the browser immediately lets the user know they’re downloading something:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=kiss_from_a_rose__dubstep_remix.mp3
```

That way you don’t open a new page just to make the file download. The file downloads, the user’s still on the page where they were when it’s downloaded, everyone’s happy.

- Fewer steps =  fewer things for users to be confused by.
- Using the browser’s UI = more chance that the user will have seen it before, and thus know what’s going on

Comment: would this work on browsers for mobile phones (java phones, android, etc)

Comment: @arinte — Not sure, I’ve not tried it. At least with the iPhone (which I own), I don’t think the web browser supports downloading files at all. So it wouldn’t work, but neither would any other solution, including meta refresh. You’d want to avoid offering a download in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

<s>unix</s> user freindly? Depends entirely on the browser, and last time I checked, most/all linux browsers and safari worked fine with meta refresh.

Which is why most websites offer meta refresh with a download link.

Comment: I think it means "user experience friendly"

Comment: The user experience will be exactly the same whether you use a meta redirect or anything else. Unless the browser you are looking at has some wierd quirks or the item to download opens in browsers there's no need for any special code.

Comment: @J V - wrong. User experience consists of many different things. See my asnwer.